# How to send the music file through sms from Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I had a requirement that I have to send music file trough SMS. Or we can send through MMS if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

You can not send file through sms. Current SDK does not allow MMS.

Rather you can use  [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: is it not possible with open url..

Comment: open url ??? what do you mean ?

Comment: Similar to telephonic call in which we are calling with url...